# storing value in session with ctools wizard

Tags: 7, chaos-tool-suite, forms

I have created a `multi-step form` using `Ctools wizard` and its working fine.

In multi step form, there is only images, so user will select the image and click on "Continue" button for next step. In the final step, I am showing the result of merged images which are selected in all previous step.

Images are rendering as ajax link in each step and when user click on any image, an ajax callback be executed.

In each step form load and ajax callback, `fid` of the images be stored in `$_SESSION` variable.

But the problem is that `$_SESSION` are not updating on the ajax call.

Suppose, there are five images in step 1 in the `Ctools multi step form`. When `step 1` load, I am storing `fid` of first image into `$_SESSION` variable and If user click on any images, I am updating the `fid` in `$_SESSION` variable.

But, if I check `print_r($_SESSION)` in next step, its not showing the updated `fid`. Its only showing `fid` of the first image in previous step.

If I check `ajax callback` in `fire bug` console, its showing correct value of `fid` and `$_SESSION` variable.

Please suggest me what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not so good with ctools, but why can't you use something like $form_state instead of cache? Or any other drupal-managed way? Just curious.

Comment: @Mołot, I was also thinking about `$form_state` as there are approx 7 step in the form, so I use `ctools`, as we can mange the each step form easily in `ctools` .But, If I will not find any solution, then I will move to `$form_state`.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot use form_state. every step will have it's own.
cache the date with [ctools_object_cache_set](http://api.acquia.com/api/ctools/includes!object-cache.inc/function/ctools_object_cache_set/7.x-1.x)

Answer (score -2):

[Here is](http://davidsonj.com/blog/how-create-multi-step-form-drupal-7) a nice example how to create customizable multistep form without ctools wizard.

Comment: Hello. This is not an answer, only a link to answer. It will become useless if the linked site goes down. Can you please edit it to include the excerpt, and paraphrase the part that answers OPs problems with passing values?

Comment: Except that Molot's comment. Thanks for sharing the link. But why `$_SESSION` are not storing the variable properly.

Comment: @JayendraKainthola I am not good with ctools wizard too. Thats why I can't answer to your question. But my opinion is, you should forget about $_SESSION variable, and create a form with the help of that link and store values in $form_state['multistep_values'] and get them at any step.

Comment: @xurshid29, thanks for your suggestion. I will consider this.

Comment: @JayendraKainthola If you want to test how this will work you can see an anction (this is my current project wich I am developing): http://www.carroza.uz/carroza.registration/individuals.do. A little bit explanation: I have a custom entity. My form's values are being stored in $form_state['multistep_values'] array, in last step I am getting all information from steps from $form_state['multistep_values'] and creating the entity.

Comment: @xurshid29, Thanks for example. This is already in my plan but doing some R&D to check if ctools hold the session or there is some another issue in code.

Comment: Can this downvoter kindly explain to me why he downvoted this answer?